# How to replace Machine Name with Domain name in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I'm get Machine Name in the WCF proxy and getting below exception while invoking WCF service

> The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message
>   because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'   was
>   not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..HTTP GET Error
>   URI: http://MyDomine.com/TCIService/TCIService/TCIService.svc?wsdl
>   The document was understood, but it could not be processed.  - The
>   WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.  -  There was
>   an error downloading
>   'http://MyMachine.Name/TCIService/TCIService/TCIService.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
>   -  The remote name could not be resolved: 'MyMachineName'

Can any one please help me fix this issue. And below is my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="MyService.TCIService.TCIService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehaviour" >
                <endpoint address="Account" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyService.TCIContract.IAccount"  >
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="Location" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyService.TCIContract.ILocation"  >
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="Camera" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyService.TCIContract.ICamera" >
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">
                </endpoint>

                <!--<host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"></add>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>-->
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyServiceBehaviour">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Can you post your service contracts and types please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response Tom.
I fixed this issue using

```
<behavior name="MyServiceBehaviour">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
</behavior>
```